# Instantiate a matrix with x zeros and the rest ones

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, numpy

I would like to be able to quickly instantiate a matrix where the first few (variable number of) cells in a row are 0, and the rest are ones.

Imagine we want a 3x4 matrix.

I have instantiated the matrix first as all ones:

```
ones = np.ones([4,3])
```

Then imagine we have an array that announces how many leading zeros there are:

```
arr = np.array([2,1,3,0]) # first row has 2 zeroes, second row 1 zero, etc
```

Required result:

```
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

Obviously this can be done in the opposite way as well, but I'd consider the approach where 1 is a default value, and zeros would be replaced.

What would be the best way to avoid some silly loop?

Answer (score 7):

Here's one way.  `n` is the number of columns in the result. The number of rows is determined by `len(arr)`.

```
In [29]: n = 5

In [30]: arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 0, 3])

In [31]: (np.arange(n) >= arr[:, np.newaxis]).astype(int)
Out[31]: 
array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

---

There are two parts to the explanation of how this works.  First, how to create a row with `m` zeros and `n-m` ones?  For that, we use `np.arange` to create a row with values [0, 1, ..., n-1]`:

```
In [35]: n
Out[35]: 5

In [36]: np.arange(n)
Out[36]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Next, compare that array to `m`:

```
In [37]: m = 2

In [38]: np.arange(n) >= m
Out[38]: array([False, False,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

That gives an array of boolean values; the first `m` values are False and the rest are True.  By casting those values to integers, we get an array of 0s and 1s:

```
In [39]: (np.arange(n) >= m).astype(int)
Out[39]: array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
```

To perform this over an *array* of `m` values (your `arr`), we use [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html); this is the second key idea of the explanation.

Note what `arr[:, np.newaxis]` gives:

```
In [40]: arr
Out[40]: array([1, 2, 3, 0, 3])

In [41]: arr[:, np.newaxis]
Out[41]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [0],
       [3]])
```

That is, `arr[:, np.newaxis]` reshapes `arr` into a 2-d array with shape (5, 1). (`arr.reshape(-1, 1)` could have been used instead.)  Now when we compare this to `np.arange(n)` (a 1-d array with length `n`), broadcasting kicks in:

```
In [42]: np.arange(n) >= arr[:, np.newaxis]
Out[42]: 
array([[False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

As @RogerFan points out in his comment, this is basically an outer product of the arguments, using the `>=` operation.

A final cast to type `int` gives the desired result:

```
In [43]: (np.arange(n) >= arr[:, np.newaxis]).astype(int)
Out[43]: 
array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of that?! ;-) Thanks for posting. (+1)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Explanation might be useful for future people visiting (though you might just be working on that now).

Comment: Actually, I'm not using a square matrix ;(

Comment: A square matrix is not required.  The shape of the result is `(len(arr), n)`, as noted in the answer.  I just happened to pick `n=5` as an example.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yea, my bad, I was using the wrong array.

Comment: To add some explanation, the pattern `a[np.newaxis, :] op b[:, np.newaxis]` is a general way to perform an outer operation on numpy arrays due to [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Comment: @PascalvKooten: Updated with an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Not as concise as I wanted (I was experimenting with [`mask_indices`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mask_indices.html#numpy.mask_indices)), but this will also do the work:

```
>>> n = 3
>>> zeros = [2, 1, 3, 0]
>>> numpy.array([[0] * zeros[i] + [1]*(n - zeros[i]) for i in range(len(zeros))])
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1]])
>>>
```

Works very simple: concatenates multiplied required number of times, one-element lists `[0]` and `[1]`, creating the array row by row.

Comment: Updated the question to explicitly exclude this answer as being valid (my mistake), though might still be useful to others. (no downvote)

Comment: @PascalvKooten Yeah, just noticed. Sorry for confusion. However there is a shorter way, just give me a minute :)

Comment: Also, make sure it also works for non-square matrices while you're at it, please.

Comment: @PascalvKooten Done - try this one please.

Comment: @PascalvKooten I doubt that you will notice any significant difference for such small matrices. I prefer to write simple and readable code first, and only after discovering and *proving* a performance problem in a particular place, optimize.

Comment: My goal will be to use it for thousands of simulations of matrices with shape [100000, 4], so for sure it will be very critical. Otherwise I'd agree with you.

Comment: @PascalvKooten Yeah, probably that's a good intuition, however I'm very sceptical when it comes to "for sure it will be very critical". Many times such intuitions of my own were proven wrong :) Your idea for benchmarking this is very good, I'll try to do this in the evening, if I won't have much other work.