# Slicing different rows of a numpy array differently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I'm working on a Monte Carlo radiative transfer code, which simulates firing photons through a medium and statistically modelling their random walk. It runs slowly firing one photon at a time, so I'd like to vectorize it and run perhaps 1000 photons at once.

I have divided my slab through which the photons are passing into `nlayers` slices between optical depth `0` and `depth`. Effectively, that means that I have `nlayers + 2` regions (`nlayers` plus the region above the slab and the region below the slab). At each step, I have to keep track of which layers each photon passes through.

Let's suppose that I already know that two photons start in layer 0. One takes a step and ends up in layer 2, and the other takes a step and ends up in layer 6. This is represented by an array `pastpresent` that looks like this:

```
[[ 0 2]
 [ 0 6]]
```

I want to generate an array `traveled_through` with `(nlayers + 2)` columns and 2 rows, describing whether photon `i` passed through layer `j` (endpoint-inclusive). It would look something like this (with `nlayers = 10`):

```
[[ 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [ 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

I could do this by iterating over the photons and generating each row of `traveled_through` individually, but that's rather slow, and sort of defeats the point of running many photons at once, so I'd rather not do that.

I tried to define the array as follows:

```
traveled_through = np.zeros((2, nlayers)).astype(int)
traveled_through[ : , np.min(pastpresent, axis = 1) : np.max(pastpresent, axis = 1) + ] = 1
```

The idea was that in a given photon's row, the indices from the starting layer through and including the ending layer would be set to 1, with all others remaining 0. However, I get the following error:

```
traveled_through[ : , np.min(pastpresent, axis = 1) : np.max(pastpresent, axis = 1) + 1 ] = 1
IndexError: invalid slice
```

My best guess is that numpy does not allow different rows of an array to be indexed differently using this method. Does anyone have suggestions for how to generate `traveled_through` for an arbitrary number of photons and an arbitrary number of layers?

Comment: Looks like a slight variation of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26130447/instantiate-a-matrix-with-x-zeros-and-the-rest-ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two photons always start at 0, you could perhaps construct your array as follows.

First setting the variables...

```
>>> pastpresent = np.array([[0, 2], [0, 6]])
>>> nlayers = 10
```

...and then constructing the array:

```
>>> (pastpresent[:,1][:,np.newaxis] + 1 > np.arange(nlayers+2)).astype(int)
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Or if the photons have an arbitrary starting layer:

```
>>> pastpresent2 = np.array([[1, 7], [3, 9]])
>>> (pastpresent2[:,0][:,np.newaxis] < np.arange(nlayers+2)) & 
    (pastpresent2[:,1][:,np.newaxis] + 1 > np.arange(nlayers+2)).astype(int)       
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: This seems to work quite well! I changed the last block of code to `(pastpresent2[:,0][:,np.newaxis] <= np.arange(nlayers+2)) & (pastpresent2[:,1][:,np.newaxis] + 1 > np.arange(nlayers+2)).astype(int)`, so that it will also return a 1 for a photon's starting layer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A little trick I kind of like for this kind of thing involves the `accumulate` method of the `logical_xor` ufunc:

```
>>> a = np.zeros(10, dtype=int)
>>> b = [3, 7]
>>> a[b] = 1
>>> a
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])
>>> np.logical_xor.accumulate(a, out=a)
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```

Note that this sets to `1` the entries between the positions in `b`, first index inclusive, last index exclusive, so you have to handle off by 1 errors depending on what exactly you are after.

With several rows, you could make it work as:

```
>>> a = np.zeros((3, 10), dtype=int)
>>> b = np.array([[1, 7], [0, 4], [3, 8]])
>>> b[:, 1] += 1  # handle the off by 1 error
>>> a[np.arange(len(b))[:, None], b] = 1
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
>>> np.logical_xor.accumulate(a, axis=1, out=a)
array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
```